# How to code menu arrow

Tags: html, menu

Can anyone help me with coding the white menu arrow (on top) upon the navigation?

Which is the best way to do this in HTML?

(I have bootstrap also installed but this site will not be responsive)

Thanks for every help!

Screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALUWF.jpg

//EDIT

I think I will put the arrow in header-image (slider) div in a new wrapper div and I'll get it in right position using a margin or padding.

Its an idea but I am sure that there is already better solution.

```
   <div id="menu">
            <div class="menuwrapper">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Služby</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">O nás</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="header-image"> 
            <div class="arrow-wrapper" style="margin: 0 auto 0 auto;">
                <div class="arrow">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: A way that I know is creating a JQuery and creating a .jpg image that looks like an arrow and just give it's functionalities

Comment: think I will put the arrow in header-image (slider) div in a new wrapper div and I'll get it in right position using a margin or padding.

Its an idea but I am sure that there is already better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are CSS triangles. You can create a triangle, and then show it relative to the element you want to be.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/